# Expression language can't access getter methods

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, el

I have the following class users.java:

```
package org.XY;

public class user {
    private String mail;
    private String name;
    private String org;
    private String pw;
    private String admin;

    public user (String mail,String name,String org, String pw, String admin){
        this.mail=mail;
        this.name=name;
        this.org=org;
        this.pw = pw;
        this.admin = admin;
    }

    public String getMail() {
        return this.mail;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getOrg() {
        return this.org;
    }

    public String getPw() {
        return this.pw;
    }

    public String getAdmin() {
        return this.admin;
    }

    public String getUser() {
        String u = this.mail + " | " + this.name + " | " + this.org + " | " + this.pw + " | Is admin:" + this.admin;
        return u;
    }

}
```

And the following jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page import="org.XY" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@page isELIgnored="false"%>


<html>
<head>
    <title>myservlet</title>
</head>
<body>

<%--<c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${user.getMail()}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.getName()}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.getOrg()}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.getPw()}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.getAdmin()}" /></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>--%>

<%
    List<user> users = (List<user>) request.getAttribute("users");
    for (user user : users) {
%>
${user.mail}
<%
    }
%>

<%
    for (user user : users) {
        out.println("<li>" + user.getPw());
    }
%>
...
```

I want to create a table which contains all the data from the users.
As you can see, I tried using the ${user.mail} method with el.

Both give me an `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: No public static field named [mail] was found on class [org.isse.sopro.user]` error and an `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: mail` error.

I already tried renaming the getter methods but it did not solv the issue.
 Could someone tell me what I am diong wrong?
Regards
Andi

UPDATE:
Obviously it wasn't about the program itself, it was about maven. After a complete reload from Intellij, maven reloaded the project and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%--<c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${user.mail}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.name}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.org}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.pw}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${user.admin}" /></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>--%>
```

Comment: He did try ${user.mail} but not success

Comment: I doubt he did. can i get a look at the controller?

Answer (score -1):

You can not use `${user.mail}` because of did not implements `Serializable`

You need change user class implements `Serializable`

```
public class user implements Serializable{
}
```

And you can use `${user.mail}` instead of `${user.getMail()}`

```
<c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${user.mail}" /></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Java EL has nothing to do with Java Serializable.